# Determine HTTP requests a web page makes using C# WebClient or WebBrowser

Tags: javascript, c#, webclient

If I use the WebClient class in C# (or similar) to request a web page is there a way of determining which requests the requested page makes, i.e. to CSS, JS or image files?

Currently I use WebClient to get the raw HTML, then parse it using [HtmlAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for images, styles and javascript files.

However this wont catch any requests made client side that may not be visible in the returned html.

Is there a way to determine which requests a page requests using the WebBrowser control or similar perhaps?

Comment: Presumably you're talking about potential ajax calls it may make, amongst other things?

Comment: Depending on what you'd want to do I'd say use FiddlerCore and make all HTTP requests go through that. Can you elaborate on why you need this?

Comment: It's to generate a daily report on the number of requests made by the home page. I'll have a look at FiddlerCore.

Comment: Yeah, this might do just the trick http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Jul/29/Using-FiddlerCore-to-capture-HTTP-Requests-with-NET

Answer (score 0):

Merely parsing through the HTML that's returned by the page will only get you part of the picture. The only way to truly determine what kind of requests a page will make is to render the page. You can do this using tools like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) with the [PhantomJS wrapper for .NET (C#)](http://www.nrecosite.com/phantomjs_wrapper_net.aspx).